# How to share image with LINE app in IONIC?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing a game using ionic and **I have a problem when trying to share image using LINE app**. It's possible to share using Facebook, Twitter etc..

*Link: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin*

But I couldn't find any solutions to share using LINE app.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you used this <button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('My message')">share!</button>.  because this code show all share apps in mobile i think. can you test it?

Comment: Hello Angu
I already use socialsharing.share('My message').
Yes, It worked. It just call all application like: facebook app, twitter app, google app but line app can not appear.

Do you have any idea about this problem?

Thank you so mush

Comment: i have given answer. can you check it? i think may useful it

Answer (score 0):

Use it . may helpful for you.
You should include Line app package Name

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.canShareVia('jp.naver.line.android', 'Hi Lineapp', null, img, null, function(e){alert(e)}, function(e){alert(e)})">Line APP</button>
```

Comment: @SinatHor  ok  is it fine?

Comment: Sorry for replay late
it just doesn't work.
Do you have any ideas?